# Sequelizejs promises returns empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelizejs and i try to create simple user validation function

```
function ValidateIsUserLogged(sessionKeyInput) {
      var result = app.get('dbContext').user
        .find({
          where: {
            sessionKey: sessionKeyInput
          }
        })
        .then(function (user) {
          return user != null;
        }, function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });

      return result;
}
```

in .then() user is fine it's the same right object and everything is well but i want to get the result outside the promise. I have tried with .success().error() and now with .then() the result is (nearly) the same i got an empty object and i can't get to the result from the function in the promise. I have tried to set a variable in .then(), but the result is the same variable doesn't change its value or function already returned the value (before the value is assigned/changed). I know it's asynchronous method and maybe the question is about promises as general, but i have stucked here for several days. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Write the sync equivalent:

```
function validateIsUserLogged(sessionKeyInput) {
    try {
        var user = app.get('dbContext').user
            .find({
                where: {
                    sessionKey: sessionKeyInput
                }
            });
        }
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    return user != null;
}
```

Modify it:

```
function validateIsUserLogged(sessionKeyInput) {
    try {
        var user = app.get('dbContext').user
            .find({
                where: {
                    sessionKey: sessionKeyInput
                }
            });
        }
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    return user;
}
```

Translating the above back to promises:

```
function validateIsUserLogged(sessionKeyInput) {
    return app.get('dbContext').user
    .find({
        where: {
            sessionKey: sessionKeyInput
        }
    }).then(function(user) {
        //This is pointless but I have no idea what you want to do
        return user;
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: I try to see if session key is valid -> so if i find a user which is not null i return it as true; in your method i get again the empty object problem

Comment: @Daemonyoyo I didn't have solution but hint that if you write code as if it was synchronous and solves the problem then that can be translated directly to promise based code